# How does this 飾る work?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011249481000/k10011249481000.html

The sentence in question:
２つ目のオリンピックの案は、客がたくさん来るように飾る「招き猫」ときつねのデザインです

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning the second idea for the olympic games, in order for many guests to come, it is a design of a decorative (="decorating") beckoning cat and a fox."

Since my literal translation is at the very edge of being comprehensible, I wanted to ask for confirmation wether I understood the use of 飾る, which probably is an attribute to 「招き猫」ときつね which itself is again an attribute to 
デザイン, correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

> ２つ目のオリンピックの案は、客がたくさん来るように飾る「招き猫」ときつねのデザインです
>
> The second proposal for Olympics is desiged in the motif of a beckoning cat, *which is displayed in order for many guests to come*, and a fox.

In this sentence 「飾る」 is "to display", not "to decorate".

The part 「客がたくさん来るように飾る」 is an attribute to 「招き猫」 but not to 「きつね」.
It describes what 「招き猫」 is, probably because a non-Japanese reader may not know what 「招き猫」 is.

This sentence may be confusing because it does not mention who and when 「招き猫」 is displayed. Actually it is describing a custom in Japan.

Comment: `who and when 「招き猫」 is displayed` -- **how** and when のタイプミスでしょうか・・

Comment: 招き猫 used to be displayed at the front of a small shop, [like in this picture](http://oneday55.exblog.jp/12315589/), but this custom is rapidly disappearing...

Comment: I always thought the 招き猫 was Chinese. Shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I think the left one is what they say in the sentence. The left character which has a motif of “Maneki-Neko” cat which is kind of a talisman and a fox which is a messenger god and worshiped in a shrine, which is for inviting guests.
 The character is decorated with Shimenawa rope in their neck which is;*in Shinto religion, a thick, twisted straw rope with stripes of white paper hung around a thing to ward off evil spirits.* and having a flame in their tail.

The italic is the excerpt from Wisdom Japanese English dictionary.

The grammar seems explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/40271/meaning/m0u/)

> **かざ・る【飾る】の意味**
>   １ 他の物を添えたり、手を加えたりするなどして、美しく見せるようにする。装飾する。「食卓を花で―・る」
>   ２ 物を、人目につくように工夫して、置き並べる。「商品をウインドーに―・る」「雛人形 (ひなにんぎょう) を壇に―・る」
>   ３ 表面をよく見せる。取り繕う。「体裁を―・る」「―・らない人柄」「言葉を―・る」
>   ４ りっぱにやり遂げることによって、価値あるものにする。華やかさやすばらしさを添える。  「白星で初日を―・る」「有終の美を―・る」「歴史の一ページを―・る壮挙」
>   ５ 設ける。構える。
>   「高座を―・ってくだされ」〈狂言記拾・泣尼〉

- 「客がたくさん来るように飾る「招き猫」ときつねのデザインです」の「飾る」は、Goo辞書の定義の２に当たります。Faily Feelyさんの答えにあるように、ここでの「飾る」の意味は、「装飾する *to decorate*」という意味より「置く *to place*」あるいは「陳列する *to display*」という意味に近いです。従って、与えれた文は「客がたくさん来るように置かれる「まねき猫」ときつねのデザインです」と言い換えても余り意味は変わりません。
- 「客がたくさん来るように陳列される」は、「まねき猫」だけを修飾し、きつねは修飾しません。これもFaily Feelyさんの答えに書かれているとおりです。
- 原文をよく読むと分かりますが、「まねき猫」ときつねは別のものではなく、オリンピック用のマスコットデザインとして、まねき猫の格好をしたきつね（あるいは、まねき猫ときつねを融合させたデザイン）ということが分かります。なぜなら、２つ目の案のパラリンピック用のデザインは「こま犬」をデザインしたものと書かれているからです。

質問者が疑問に感じるように、与えられた文（Ａ）は分かりにくい文です。私なら（Ｂ）のように書き換えます。

> (Ａ)２つ目のオリンピックの案は、客がたくさん来るように飾る「招き猫」ときつねのデザインです。
>   (Ｂ)２つ目のオリンピックの案は、「まねき猫」ときつねを合体させたようなデザインです。「まねき猫」は、お客さんがたくさん来るように店頭などに置かれる猫の置物ですね。